# iterate through JSON array with mustache

Tags: json, mustache

I am new to Mustache, please bear with me :)

I have an array in my JSON

```
"prop":{"brands":["nike","adidas","puma"]}
```

if I have the template like this

```
{{#prop}}
 <b>{{brands}}</b>
{{prop}}
```

and I want to get something like:

```
<b>nike</b>
<b>adidas</b>
<b>puma</b>
```

I understand the elements in the array are not hash key-value pairs, however I am wondering if there is anyway in mustache that I can iterate through the elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mustache is logicless, so writing your own iteration/loop in it is impossible. It is easy to convert your JSON though. For example:

```
var json = '{"prop":{"brands":["nike","adidas","puma"]}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var data = {brands: obj.prop['brands'].map(function(x){ return {name: x}; })};
```

Gives you a `data` variable which will work with the template:

```
{{#brands}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/brands}}
```

Comment: Thanks, parsing the JSON before hand seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 41):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qa4UX/

Basically, you need to iterate over the brands array.
Since your array is raw and does not have objects inside you have to reference each string like so:

```
{{#props}}
  <ul>
  {{#brands}}
    <li>
    {{#.}}
        <b>{{.}}</b>
    {{/.}}
    </li>
  {{/brands}}
  </ul>
{{/props}}
```

You can also find many more examples over here: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#mustachejs---logic-less-mustache-templates-with-javascript

Comment: thanks for the answer Paul, I see your point and think it would be a solution, however I can't seem to get the fiddle example to produce html result whenI hit "run", but a very nice solution, thanks!

Comment: hi. Just out of curiosity: Don't you see the list in the html frame in jsfiddle?

Comment: Nope, <div id="testmustache"></div> is all I see, and the "Run" link does nothing to it...

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. The problem was that mustache was not loaded in Chrome, but worked in Safari. I changed the mustache source and now it should work

Comment: Thank you for this and the JS-Fiddle. Is the `{{#.}}` and `{{/.}}` part mandatory/best practice ? I couldn't find documentation on this

Comment: @brclz It's because it isn't documented.

Answer (score 24):

This works

```
{{#json.props.brands}}
<h1>{{.}}</h1>
{{/json.props.brands}}
```

`{{.}}` When looping over an array of strings, a `.` can be used to refer to the current item in the list.