# ICanHaz.js - Possible to use an array of strings in section instead of key/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, mustache, icanhaz.js

My situation is as follows:

I receive an object from an AJAX call which contains an array of strings (not key/value pairs). It would be amazing if I could just take that array and toss it into the template's data object like the below, and then recursively show each value in the array via the ICanHaz `mustache` section template syntax. Unfortunately I can not get it to work without key/value pairs to reference inside the section template.

This is a major pain because I have to go into the array returned from AJAX and add key value pairs.

I could not find anything on the [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) or [ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) documentation dealing with this matter.

**Javascript**:

```
var listOfStuff = {
    name: 'This is not important',
    stuff: data.ajaxreturnedarray || [1, 2, 3, 4]  // Just for example.
};

$("#new").append(ich.test(listOfStuff));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="new">Test</div>

<script type="text/html" id="test">
<div class="panel">
    {{#stuff}}<p>{{stuff}}</p>{{/stuff}}
    {{^stuff}}<p>No items :(</p>{{/stuff}}
</div>
</script>
```

Does anyone know a way to make this work?

---

**Update**

This is covered in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283776/iterate-through-json-array-with-mustache), but it does not mention `ICanHaz.js` so I cross-reference for anyone googling this problem with ICanHaz.js without `mustache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, ICanHaz embeds Mustache, and if it's Mustache you can simply do

```
{{#stuff}}<p>{{.}}</p>{{/stuff}}
```

Comment: works like a charm thank you. Is this somewhere in the Mustache documentation?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), under the paragraph "Non-empty lists".