# Generally convert a mustache template to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

When working with Mustache, or any templating engine, a properly structured JSON object is needed to render some specific template. Generally (I believe), a developer knows their application's data model, and how they want to show data in a template, but find that their data model doesn't perfectly output JSON in the form their templates expect. So we often need to write data processing functions that **transform** data model outputs into acceptable mustache template inputs.

For example, [@Liang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17283776/3491991)'s application outputs a JSON array like:

```
"prop":{"brands":["nike","adidas","puma"]}
```

but his template expects it to be in the form:

```
"brands":[{"name":"nike"},{"name":"adidas"},{"name":"puma"}]
```

so he needs to transform it via:

```
var data = {brands: obj.prop['brands'].map(function(x){ return {name: x}; })};
```

Liang also could have [tweaked his template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284342/3491991) to get it working without a data transformation step. But what if I don't know what the template is before hand and my only template guarantee is that its tags resolve to keys in my data model. Is it possible to write a function `bridge(data_model, template)` which takes as input the data model and mustache template and outputs the transformation function `Transform`. Such that `Transform` itself is the code which massages the data model outputs into acceptable mustache template inputs.

Said another way, if

`data_model = "prop":{"brands":["nike","adidas","puma"]}`

and

`template = {{#brands}}
             <b>{{name}}</b>
           {{/brands}}`

then what `bridge` produces the javascript

`{brands: obj.prop['brands'].map(function(x){ return {name: x}; })}` = `bridge(data_model, template)`

(the output of `bridge` would be javascript code).

I understand that this may be too unconstrained to give a good answer, but I think everyone can recognize that at a minimum, `bridge` would need to be able to output nested `for loops` or `map` commands. How could I go about making perhaps a crude version of `bridge` that has `for loop` commands in the right places respective to mustache tags?.. sorry if this doesn't make great sense, it's a challenging question for me to articulate. Honestly, it feels a bit like asking for magic.

Comment: _"the output of bridge would be javascript code"_ Why would it not simply transform the data and return that data? Producing JS code may not be as easy. That being said, the [source code of Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js) is pretty small _(416 lines if you remove comments and empty lines)_. If you look at it, it compiles the templates, to extract tokens. Your best bet may be to reuse their parsing logic to build a tree of props

Comment: Well, sure, it could transform the data too... I do like your idea

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Then I think the correct way to think of it is not that it will produce JS code, but rather use an internal logic to apply different transformations based on the input data and the tree it finds in the template. That's an interesting question. Not 100% sure it's doable, but I'll look into it.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking. I wrote it that way to emphasize that `bridge` may need to author actual code... such as in deciding how to nest `map` operations that would produce the needed transformation. But as you say, yes, ideally it would just output the transformed data ready and pretty for mustache, for any arbitrary (`data_model`,`template`) pair. I'm also not sure it's doable but appreciate your consideration :)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't in javascript but R3M (written in php) can template json files as well. it syntax is borrowed from Smarty but different. it will reach production stability in 2023. It enables templates which can be used in .js, .json & .tpl.

```
{
  "books": "{json.select($url, 'book')}"
}
```

see https://github.com/like-it/r3m-framework